# Gaussian Mixture Countour Plots for 3-D data

Tags: python, curve-fitting, gaussian, gmm

How to plot Gaussian Mixture contour fits for 3 dimensional data? I cannot figure out how to transform Z.

Obtain a projection of the fitted mixture of normal distributions on each plane, i.e. x-y, x-z, and
y-z. 
This is the exact question which i cannot figure out.

Comment: can you show what did you try ?

Comment: How about "plt.plot(xData, yData,  'D')", "plt.plot(xData, zData,  'D')", and "plt.plot(yData, zData,  'D')"?